# Add a sentence in each line of a file with sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file with this content:

```
dog 
cat
```

and I want to add a sentence (I have a) before every sentence, so the new content should be:

```
I have a dog
I have a cat
```

I tried with

```
sed -i 'I have a ' file
```

But I get something like this

```
I have a 
dog
I have a
cat
```

Which would be the correct use of sed? Is there another way of doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^/I have a /' file
cat file
I have a dog
I have a cat
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '{print "I have a", $0}' file
I have a dog
I have a cat
```

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "I have a $line"
done < file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

Basically, read each line and echo them back with the leading title. Then redirect to a temp file. In case the command succeeds, then move the temp file into the original one.

---

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print "I have a", $0}' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

---

With `sed`: check [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018960/1983854) for the best way. This can be another.

```
sed -i.bak -n 's/^/I have a /p' file
```

Note it is good practice to use `-i.bak` (or `-i.whatever`) to generate a backup file with the `.bak` extension.

---

Just for fun, you can also use `paste`:

```
$ paste -d" " <(printf "%0.sI have a\n" $(seq $(wc -l <file))) file
I have a dog
I have a cat
```

#### Explanation

- `paste -d" " file1 file` prints two files side by side, with space as `d`elimiter.
- `printf "%0.sI have a\n" $(seq $(wc -l <file))` print "I have a" as many times a lines `file` has.

  ```
  $ wc -l <a
  2
  $ seq $(wc -l <a)
  1
  2
  $ printf "%0.sI have a\n" $(seq $(wc -l <a))
  I have a
  I have a
  ```

Comment: +1 for such a complete answer to such a question.

Comment: I suggest not calling the variable `word` in `while read word`, because in the general case it doesn't just read a single word. Generally, adding `-r` to prevent `read` from interpreting the input is also a good idea.

Comment: @mklement0 fair enough, just changed it to `line` so it is more clear what does it catch. Also, regarding `-r`, I know see in `man bash` that `-r --> Backslash does not act as an escape character.  The backslash is considered to be part of the line.  In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.`. Thanks for both!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/^/I have a /' your_file
```